# Prove an equation about binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Could we prove:

$ \sum_{k} \binom{2k}{k}\binom{n+k}{m+2k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} = \binom{n-1}{m-1}$ when $m,n \in N$

Answer (score 2):

When $n=1$ it's easy to evaluate for all $m\ge1$. Then it's easy to prove the $n+1$ by induction, given the $n$ case (for all $m$): just write
$$
\binom{n+k}{m+2k} = \binom{n-1+k}{m+2k} + \binom{n-1+k}{m-1+2k}.
$$

Comment: Pretty helpful! Could you tell me what's the value of $\binom{x}{y}$ if $x<y$ ?

Comment: @cinvro: Zero. For a nonnegative integer $y$ and any arbitrary (e.g. complex number) $x$, the expression $\binom{x}{y}$ is defined as $\dfrac{x(x-1)\cdots(x-y+1)}{y!}$. When $0 \le x < y$ (and $x$ is an integer), this becomes $0$, because of the factor $(x-x)$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

The generating function for the [Central Binomial Coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}x^k=(1-4x)^{-1/2}\tag{1}
$$
Integrating $(1)$ and dividing by $x$ yields
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}\frac{x^k}{k+1}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\tag{2}
$$
Sum the formula against $x^m$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{m=-\infty}^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n+k}{m+2k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\right)x^m\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-2k}^{n-k}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n+k}{m+2k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}x^m\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{-2k}\sum_{m=0}^{n+k}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n+k}{m}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}x^m\tag{5}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{-2k}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}(x+1)^{n+k}\tag{6}\\
&=(x+1)^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\left(\frac{x+1}{x^2}\right)^{k}\tag{7}\\
&=(x+1)^n\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\frac{x+1}{x^2}}}{2\frac{x+1}{x^2}}\tag{8}\\
&=x(x+1)^{n-1}\frac{-x+(x+2)}{2}\tag{9}\\[9pt]
&=x(x+1)^{n-1}\tag{10}\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{m=1}^n\binom{n-1}{m-1}x^m\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
Justification:
$\:\ (3)$: sum against $x^m$
$\:\ (4)$: change order of summation
$\:\ (5)$: substitute $m\mapsto m-2k$
$\:\ (6)$: apply the Binomial Theorem
$\:\ (7)$: reorganize
$\:\ (8)$: apply $(2)$
$\:\ (9)$: simplify
$(10)$: simplify
$(11)$: apply the Binomial Theorem

Equating coefficients of $x^m$ yields
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n+k}{m+2k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}=\binom{n-1}{m-1}\tag{12}
$$

---

Note that the sum has non-zero terms for $m\lt1$, but these cancel; e.g. $n=3,m=-1$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\binom{0}{0}\binom{3}{-1}\frac11-\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}\frac12+\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{3}\frac13-\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{5}\frac14+\binom{8}{4}\binom{7}{7}\frac15\\[6pt]
&=0-4+20-30+14\\[9pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't quite understand how you get equation(2). And I am not sure how you get $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{-2k}$ in the sum too. Can you explain them a lithe bit?

Comment: Oh I figured out the second question I put above.

Comment: @cinvro: Equation $(2)$ follows by integrating both sides of $(1)$ and dividing by $x$. The left side is computed term by term, the right side by finding the anti-derivative.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused by (4). After change order of summation, why the lower bound of $m$ is $-2k$? and upper bound is $n-k$?

Comment: And when you compare (3) and (11) to say that (12) holds. I don't get it since (3) has summation with $m$ from $-\infty$ to $n$, but (11) only has summation with $m$ from $1$ to $n$

Comment: @cinvro: "I'm still a little bit confused by (4)." Actually $$\sum_{m=-\infty}^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-\infty}^{n-k}$$ However, if $m\lt-2k$, we would have $\binom{n+k}{m+2k}=0$. Therefore, I limited $m\ge-2k$.

Comment: @cinvro: "And when you compare (3) and (11) to say that (12) holds." As I said later, that the terms with $m\lt1$ vanish means that the sums with $m\lt1$ cancel. I show an example with $n=3$ and $m=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar approach using basic complex variables.
Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{k\ge 0} {2k\choose k} {n+k\choose m+2k} 
\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$$
where $n\ge m.$

Introduce the integral representation
$${n+k\choose m+2k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+2k+1}} (1+z)^{n+k} \; dz.$$

This yields the following integral for the sum:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} {2k\choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}
\frac{1}{z^{m+2k+1}} (1+z)^{n+k} \; dz
\\= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{m+1}}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {2k\choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}
\frac{(1+z)^k}{z^{2k}} \; dz.$$

Now the OGF of the Catalan numbers is
$$\sum_{k\ge 0} {2k\choose k} \frac{1}{k+1} w^k
= \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4w}}{2w}.$$
Substituting this closed form that we computed
into the integral yields

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{m+1}}
\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4(1+z)/z^2}}{(-1)\times 2(1+z)/z^2} \; dz
\\= - \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{m-1}}
\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4(1+z)/z^2}}{2(1+z)} \; dz
\\= - \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^m}
\frac{z-\sqrt{z^2+4(1+z)}}{2(1+z)} \; dz.$$

Observe that $z^2+4(1+z) = (z+2)^2$ so the integral becomes
$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^m}
\frac{z-(z+2)}{2(1+z)} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n-1}}{z^m} \; dz.$$

This last integral can be evaluated by inspection and yields
$$[z^{m-1}] (1+z)^{n-1} =
{n-1\choose m-1}.$$

Note that for the convergence of the Catalan GF series we require $|(1+z)/z^2|\lt 1/4$ (distance to the nearest singularity). Now $|(1+z)/z^2|\le (1+\epsilon)/\epsilon^2$ so we may take $\epsilon = N \ge 5.$

Remark: the same functions appear here as in @robjohn's answer,
who was first.

A trace as to when this method appeared on MSE and by whom starts at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792567/).