# How to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n+k}{2k+1}C_k=1$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

How to prove the following identity?
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n+k}{2k+1}C_k=1
$$
where $C_k$ is the $k$th Catalan number, $C_n=\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}$.

This question is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4333062/an-identity-involving-catalan-numbers-and-binomial-coefficients?r=SearchResults)
but are different. For the problem in the link $m$ is in the second line of $\binom{s}{m-s}$, while for my problem $n$ is in the first line of $\binom{n+k}{2k+1}$. Therefore I tried the method in the link but it doesn't work.

Proofs, hints, or references are all welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove an equation about binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697170/prove-an-equation-about-binomial-coefficients) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5Ek%7D%7Bk%2B1%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%2Bk%7D%7B2k%2B1%7D%5Cbinom%7B2k%7D%7Bk%7D%3D1%24&p=1). Note inserting the definition $C_k$ into the summation gives $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\binom{n+k}{2k+1}\binom{2k}{k}=1$, & your equation is a special case with $m=1$ since $\binom{n-1}{m-1}=1$. ...

Comment: (cont.) FYI, a quite similar problem in the results list is [Calculate $\sum_{0 \le k } \binom{n+k}{2k} \binom{2k}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$](/q/3174979). Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.